# "Putzig" - hat das was mit "putzen" zu tun?

Tags: etymology

Hat das Wort "putzig" (niedlich, goldig, possierlich) irgendwas mit dem Verb "putzen" zu tun?

Comment: Womöglich, weil sich Tierkinder so häufig putzen? Oder vom Muttertier geputzt werden?

Comment: Bauchgefühl: Von Putz = Schmuck, Verzierungen. Vgl. “herausgeputzt”. Ohne Belege, deshalb als Kommentar.

Comment: @userunknown Früher dachte ich immer, "putzig" käme von meinem Hamster, der sich immer so schön die Schnurrhaare putzte, was wirklich putzig war. Inzwischen bin ich mir da nicht mehr so sicher.

Answer (score 3):

Im [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/putzig) ist als (belegte) Wortherkunft *Butz (Kobold)* genannt:

> Herkunft:
>
> Derivation (Ableitung) vom niederdeutschen Substantiv Butz („Kobold“)
>   mit dem Derivatem (Ableitungsmorphem) -ig, daher in der ursprünglichen
>   Bedeutung „koboldhaft“,[1] belegt seit dem 18. Jahrhundert[2]

Für *putzen* ist als Herkunft *butzen* [genannt](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/putzen)

> Herkunft:
>
> [1] frühneuhochdeutsch butzen, putzen „säubern“, belegt seit dem 15.
>   Jahrhundert; weitere Herkunft ungeklärt[1]

Auch *butzen* ist vom Substantiv *Butz* abgeleitet, allerdings in der Bedeutung *"Schmutz"*.

Laut @IQV's [Kommentar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/41947/putzig-hat-das-was-mit-putzen-zu-tun#comment104287_41948) findet sich weder im DWDS oder dem Grimm'schen Wörterbuch ein Hinweis auf einen gemeinsammen Stamm der Wörter.

Comment: Wenn man die Erläuterungen in DWDS oder dem Grimm'schen Wörterbuch liest, findet sich kein einziger Hinweis auf einen gemeinsamen Stamm.

Comment: @IQV Danke. Allerdings könnte ich mir eine gewisse Verwandtschaft von _Butz (Kobold, Schreckgestalt)_ und _Butz (Schmutz)_ schon vorstellen.